# Concorda que [angular] não deveria ser sinônimo de [angularjs]?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags-sinônimas

O framework [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (versão 1.x) é **completamente** diferente do [Angular](https://angular.io/) (versões 2.x e 4.x). Da primeira para a segunda versão a Google reescreveu o código do framework, mantendo unicamente seu conceito. Os dois não são compatíveis.

- [SOen: Angular vs Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2)
- [Wikipedia: AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS)
- [Wikipedia: Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(application_platform))

Veja que no Wikipedia, ao acessar a página do Angular é exibida a seguinte mensagem:

> This article is about Angular. For AngularJS 1.x, see AngularJS.

O que reitera Angular e AngularJS serem duas coisas **diferentes**. Mesmo assim, a tag [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) é um sinônimo para [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

Outro problema é a tag [angular-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2) que não faz sentido já que a Google passou a chamar as versões 2 e 4 para somente e simplesmente Angular

O SOen também discutiu o assunto:

- [What to do about Angular 2?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2)
- [Now can we burninate the Angular4 tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346072/now-can-we-burninate-the-angular4-tag)
- [Should there be a separate 'angularjs-2.0' tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291347/6241184) (ainda quando não existia o termo Angular para se referir à versão 2.x)

A minha proposta é mover todas as questões das tags [angular-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2) e [angular-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-4) para [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) e manter a [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) para o uso exclusivo da versão 1.x.

O que acham?

Comment: Concordo, vim aqui no meta justamente para propor isso, pois [tag:angular] não é [tag:angularjs], como os sinônimos de tags sugerem. Já [tag:angular-2] e [tag:angular-4] (e/ou [tag:angular2] e [tag:angular4]) deveriam ser sinonimos de [tag:angular], sendo que oficialmente as tags oficiais seriam [tag:angularjs] para angularjs 1.x e [tag:angular] para Angular 2.x e Angular 4.x+.

Comment: Eu concordo demais, inclusive dupliquei a sua publicação pra dizer isto.

Comment: vnbrs, @FernandoLeal as edições das tags nas perguntas selecionadas foram feitas as 5h da manhã de hoje horário de brasília, se tiver algo a mais para ser feito é só falar :)

Comment: @Math, observei algumas perguntas aleatórias, e a edição das tags me parece perfeita, as unicas que pode ser que deviria manter angularjs (mas não tinha o que fazer pois depende do contexto), foi essas 2 questões que já as editei (se achar melhor sinta-se a vontade para reverter): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165865/2998 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141669/2998.

Comment: @FernandoLeal esses casos ai realmente faz sentido arrumar (do jeito que você arrumou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei os seguintes sinônimos:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não existe tags angular-1.x então a tag [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) ficou sem sinônimos

Comment: Massa! Obrigado 

Comment: Ainda não fiz a mescla das tags pois ainda falta aplicarmos a "Estrategia de migração" do Fernando, e se mesclar vai atrapalhar de fazer isso

Comment: @vnbrs confira se essa query está ok de acordo com a estratégia de migração https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/808567/estrategia-de-migracao

Comment: @Math, agora que vi que você já colocou como sinônimo, os angular-N. Bom trabalho. Obrigado por dar atenção a isso, eu já tava perdendo a esperança.

Comment: @FernandoLeal opa, obrigado, e desculpa a demora, é que como tem mt assunto a ser tratado alguns acabam passando batido as vezes, pode pingar no chat quando for assim, e obrigado vc por fazer esse levantamento das tags. Amanhã eu termino essa tarefa junto com o JNat

Answer (score 5):

**Concordo**, vim aqui no meta justamente para propor isso, pois [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) não é [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), como os sinônimos de tags sugerem. Já [angular-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2) e [angular-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-4) (e/ou [angular2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) e [angular4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4)) deveriam ser sinonimos de [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), sendo que oficialmente as tags oficiais seriam [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) para angularjs 1.x e [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) para Angular 2.x e Angular 4.x+.

Acho que deveriamos nesse caso seguir o que foi feito na SO.

- [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info), sinônimos: angular4, angular2, angular4.x
- [Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info), sinônimos: angular.js, angular1.x

Inclusive não concordo com as afirmações da [resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6370/2998) (inclusive votei contra por discordar, =D), pois minha "UserExperience" com essas tags aqui no SOpt é muito ruim, pois atualmente só trabalho com as versões angular 2.x+ e nada com angularjs 1.x, e ao procurar por problemas a primeira coisa que olho na pergunta é as tags se é [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) ou [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), para não perder tempo olhando respostas que não correspondem a tecnologia que estou utilizando.

Então acredito que tornar a classificação de tags mais claras é fundamental para manter isso de forma organizada para o futuro, hoje já seria um problema identificar as tags certas para realizar a migração conforme proposto.

Comentando sobre os argumentos do [comentário de @Guilherme Nascimento a sua resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6370/2998), não tenho conhecimento sobre Laravel, mas acredito que a mudança entre as versões 4 e 5 não alterou a linguagem utilizada para programação (acredito que ainda seja PHP). Que foi o que aconteceu com Angular, que oficialmente é mantido em TypeScript (sendo que também Dart e javascript (acho que atualmente só em TypeScript mesmo pois não tem mas nenhuma referencia na documentação oficial sobre isso)), apesar de TypeScript gerar javascript no fim, isso muda o paradigma de programação com angular em relação a angularjs, sendo que implementações e respostas em angularjs 1.x não são em sua grande maioria validas para Angular 2.x+.

> Por favor considerem melhorar essas tags.

---

### Estrategia de migração

Estrategia de separação das perguntas, que seria, entre [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) e [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), hoje só há [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), então uma forma mais fácil, seria desvincular a [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) de sinônimo de [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), e trocar todas as tags de perguntas de [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) para [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) onde também estiverem as tags: [typescript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) ou/e [angular-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2) ou/e [angular-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-4) ou/e [angular-5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-5) ou/e [ionic2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic2) ou/e [ionic3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic3), etc(outras tags que indiquem que isso é referente a angular ("novo")). Não sei se há ferramenta para fazer essa *query* de migração.

Comment: Não discordo totalmente da sua resposta, na verdade acho uma otima visão, no entanto TypeScript no final será JavaScript, claro que não para o desenvolvedor, acho que realmente você esta certo neste ponto, devemos separar ambas tags então (ou considerar como opção). No entanto sua discordância sobre UX se baseia no seu entendimento e não de usuários menos experientes, e foi nisto que basei minha resposta, por isso mesmo eu disse, se necessário resolveríamos no Wiki de tag e com tags de versão, 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: ... A minha proposta foi melhorar o entendimento e não dizer que Angular.js e Angular são idênticos, na verdade eu deixei bem claro que ambos são coisas diferentes, mas é claro que Angular 2 nasceu como uma nova versão do angular.js... Sobre o Laravel a linguagem pode até ser PHP, mas o framework e as quase linguagens que o 5 possui por exemplo, como `.blade.php` mesclam PHP com uma sintaxe própria, no Laravel também existe agora o uso de Node.js para a camada front-end. Eu não vou entrar em detalhes, mas a questão de UX dos usuários menos experientes que nós é uma coisa a se considerar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, entendo seu ponto de vista e sua resposta, e não é por que discordo em alguns pontos que ela está incorreto ou seja inválida (até é interessante ter opiniões diferentes para apresentar diferentes ponto e para o pessoal votar e opinar), só citei para contextualizar e por os pontos que eu acredito ser relevante. Em relação a UX a separação como proposto é a melhor opção mesmo para usuário menos experientes, pois a Google usa essa nomeação nas documentações, então ela seria o mais obvio, até mesmo para os novatos...

Comment: ... o que não pode é o usuário seguir a nomeação da documentação e ao colocar [tag:angular] (para se referir a angular 2.x e 4.x) e os sinônimos aqui do SOpt sugerir que seja [tag:angular.js]. E em relação ao Laravel, como te falei, talvez não seria o mesmo cenário, já que não tenho conhecimento sobre ele e nem PHP, só tentei deixar claro as diferenças entre [tag:angular.js] e [tag:angular].

Comment: Acho que esta bem claro que eu entendo a diferença entre o angular.js e angular, tanto que a pergunta aqui quando feita foi o que me ajudou a pesquisar sobre o assunto, agora como eu disse, o wiki de tag pode perfeitamente falar de muitos assuntos, desde que sejam interessantes, por exemplo usar a propria wiki de tag para diferenciar Angular de Angular.js.

Comment: Seriam essas as perguntas a terem as tags trocadas de acordo com a sua estratégia de migração? https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/808567/estrategia-de-migracao

Comment: @Math, acredito que algo como isso, e posteriormente sumir com tudo que é angular-2, angular-3, 4 e 5. já que tudo isso deve ser angular. No caso as que já tenham essas tags pode trocar angularjs e angular-N somente por angular.

Comment: @Math, por curiosidade, tem algum processo automatizado para fazer essas migrações ou tem que selecionar os alvos e alterar na mão? Acredito que tenha isso para vocês admins né?

Comment: Tem como fazer automatizado sim, eu fiquei encarregado de montar a query e o JNat vai fazer as mudanças nas tags com o retorno dela