# Notificação de perguntas no Meta

Tags: suporte, notificações

Fiz duas perguntas ([1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6372/erro-ao-editar-perguntas-na-vers%C3%A3o-mobile); [2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6369/concorda-que-angular-n%C3%A3o-deveria-ser-sin%C3%B4nimo-de-angularjs)) aqui no Meta mas não recebo notificações dos *upvotes*/*downvotes* e respostas delas.

É um bug ou não existe notificação nas publicações aqui?

Comment: Não há notificação de votos no meta. Quanto a notificação de respostas, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Você não recebeu respostas naquela pergunta, estaria se referindo aos comentários? Esses devem ser notificados pelo sistema

Comment: Errei os links. Na realidade fiz duas perguntas, uma tem respostas. Já já edito

Comment: Eu creio que não haja notificação de upvotes por alguns motivos: (a) a pontuação do meta não é explícita, usa-se a do site pai; (b) evitar gameficação onde seria mais seguro não ter

Comment: Não recebeu a notificação do [meu comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6372/erro-ao-editar-perguntas-na-vers%C3%A3o-mobile#comment24614_6372) lá? Será que não fez confusão? Sobre respostas e upvotes o pessoal já respondeu acima, não há respostas na pergunta e os votos no Meta não afetam teu score pessoal.

Comment: Os comentários no meta geram notificações, isso eu tenho a certeza. E a lógica por detrás de os votos não gerarem notificações é porque eles não afetam a reputação, logo eles preferiram não baralhar os usuários e simplesmente não notificar.

Comment: Geram sim. Acabei de receber desse. :P @Isac

Comment: Eu acabei de receber uma notificação de comentário na minha pergunta aqui no meta, usando o app do StackExchange (não sei se isso influi, acho que não)