# Precisamos conversar sobre os Angular's

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

A tag **[angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)**, hoje, é sinônimo "secundário" da tag **[angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)**. Isto é resquício de quando só existia um Angular e **a vida era muito mais fácil**.

Já faz um bom tempo que existe o novo Angular, que inicialmente era chamado de Angular 2 — não estou certo sobre este nome atualmente. De qualquer forma, aparentemente, se usa o nome AngularJS ([angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org/)) para se referir ao antigo e Angular ([angular.io](https://angular.io/)) para o novo

O problema é que isto leva muitos usuários a usarem a tag [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) em perguntas que deveriam usar a tag [angular-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2).

Um exemplo recente (de um usuário experiente): [Como trabalhar com mensagens de validação no Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269587/18246)

Outro exemplo: [Erro ao tentar salvar no banco com Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269778/18246)

Outro: [Como inserir HTML dentro de um component Angular 4?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270755/18246)

Podemos arrumar isto?

Minha primeira ideia era simplesmente alterar o sinônimo `angular` para `angular-2` e manter a segunda como principal, mas isto pode fazer os usuários de `angularjs` se confundirem pelo costume em usar a tag `angular`. Não sei se isso pode ser um grande problema, mas achei bom considerar.

---

**Update:**

Deveríamos fazer como o Fernando sugeriu na *thread* original

#### Angular 1.x

Usar a tag **`angularjs`** como principal e, **opcionalmente**, como sinônimos: `angular.js` e `angular1.x`.

#### Angular 2

Usar a tag **`angular`** **como principal**como principal e, **opcionalmente**, como sinônimos: `angular-2`, `angular-4`, `angular2.x`, `angular4.x` e similares.

Os sinônimos, neste caso são um problema a parte. Temos que ver como está o padrão do site sobre tags de versões. O importante aqui é fazer com que **`AngularJS`** e **`Angular`** sejam duas tags diferentes.

Comment: Precisamos muito arrumar isso...

Comment: De fato, @vnbrs. Está péssimo.

Comment: Coloquem as sugestões de estratégia porque a mudança é obviamente necessária.

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta no post original.

Comment: @Maniero Fiz um update na pergunta mesmo.

Comment: Quando falei de estratégia me refiro como fazer a separação porque tem muita coisa que está com a *tag* errada, vai dar um enorme trabalho. E tenho minhas dúvidas se as *tags* `angularX.Y` são úteis.

Comment: @Maniero Tem muita coisa com a tag errada? Se te refere a perguntas usando a tag `angular`, não tem nenhuma, porque ela hoje é sinônima de angularjs e o sistema troca a tag para a principal.

Comment: As que estão erradas vão continuar, mas vamos evitar que isso aconteça no futuro.

Comment: mas deve ter um monte de perguntas que já é o novo Angular sendo tratado como o antigo, não tem como separar isso a não ser manualmente. Ou acha que tem? A não ser que a sua sugestão é deixar o que está errado assim mesmo. Inclusive sempre terá gente nova usando errado pra frente. Isto nunca acaba.

Comment: Isso, a ideia é deixar o que já está errado continuar errado. A intenção é fazer este ajuste pra evitar os erros, com certeza sempre vão haver erros, mas é certo que eles vão diminuir com o ajuste das tags.

Comment: Existe alguma razão para ter as duas *tags*? Deveria? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269921/101

Comment: Não gosto muito da ideia de deixar errado. Claro que uma solução mais ou menos é melhor que nenhuma, mas acho ruim.

Comment: @Maniero Provavelmente ele usou a tag Angular2 para se referir a tecnologia e Angular4 para se referir à versão.

Comment: @Maniero, nenhuma razão, é uma redundância, talvez ele quiz, angular2 (para dizer que era angular) e angular4 (para a versão que ele utiliza no problema, mas angular 4 tem que ser referente a angular "novo").

Comment: @Maniero, referente a estrategia de separação das perguntas, que seria, entre [tag:angular] e [tag:angularjs], hoje só há [tag:angularjs], então uma forma mais fácil, seria desvincular a [tag:angular] de sinônimo de [tag:angularjs], e trocar todas as tags de perguntas de [tag:angularjs] para [tag:angular] onde também estiver as tags: [tag:typescript] ou/e [tag:angular-2] ou/e [tag:angular-4] ou/e [tag:angular-5] ou/e [tag:ionic2] ou/e [tag:ionic3], etc(outras tags que indiquem que isso é referente a angular ("novo")). Não sei se há ferramenta para fazer essa _query_ de migração. O que acha?

Comment: @Maniero, editei a [minha resposta ao poste original](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6458/2998), com a estrategia que coloquei aqui no comentário. Então fiquem a vontade para aperfeiçoar de maneira que seja aplicável, para resolver isso logo, pois isso já vem rolando errado a muito tempo.

Comment: eu não domino Angular (angular.io), mas achei a sugestão no seu update, sobre os sinônimos principalmente a melhor saída, caberia muito bem como uma resposta na outra pergunta.